# Django and MongoDB in E-commerce?

Tags: django, mongodb, e-commerce, tornado, nosql

sorry for this silly questions,

- can someone share experience about combining Django in e-commerce when used with NoSql, if it's not MongoDB, so what about CouchDB or other Non-Document nosql?
- which webserver to use when using e-commerce, cherrypy seems to have SSL? so Tornado is obsolete when using e-commerce + django?

Comment: Why is the word "e-commerce" in this question at all?  What does "e-commerce" mean in this question?  Why mention it?  If it's removed, then the question seems to be the same.

Comment: i did it, because the problem is e-commerce is that it respects the ACID, which is not the case in nosql, so is it good thing to use nosql in django (something that is efficient and that we can trust)

Comment: @S.Lott: Actually I disagree with you, product attributes are easily "modeled" with a schema-free database like MongoDB / CouchDB and then there is the whole durability issue which can cause problems if you're not careful (processing payments for instance).

Comment: @abdel: If ACID is a requirement, then actually say that.  Don't "imply" it through buzzwords like "e-commerce".

Comment: Alix Axel: "product attributes are easily "modeled" with a schema-free database"?  While true, it doesn't seem to address the use of the vague, difficult to understand term "e-commerce" in the question.  "the whole durability issue"?  Has nothing to do with "e-commerce".  Does it?  How does anyone know that "e-commerce" means "durability"?  Or  product attributes modeling?  If these are actual requirements, they should actually be in the question.

Comment: i said that because i've read something about e-commerce and that is used heavily with SQL, and because i'll only use Django and a python webserver, i want to know how it works, i'm not a pro, am just a beginner, and maybe those words (like e-commerce, e-learning...) make me feel in some "nirvana" when i write them :D

Comment: @abdel: Your feelings don't help.  What helps are actual definitions.  What do you think you mean?  Write down the definition in the question.  We can't guess what you mean.  We can't answer if we don't know what you mean.

Comment: @Alix Axel: "e-commerce implies"?  Really?  Is that relevant to this question?  How do you know that some implication is relevant to this question?

Comment: my question was simple: django + mongodb (or any other nosql) can be something that we can trust to make a serious e-commerce platform?
sorry, my english is bad, am from Algeria, and here there is no e-commerce, but it seems that sooner they'll implement it, so i try to know experience from other countries.

Comment: @S.Lott: I can't expect everyone to have the same level of understanding, I just knew the OP was aware of ACID after I posted my comment... Either way, e-commerce implies more careful considerations and design than say, a logging system or something like Twitter. If you lose a tweet it's just < 140 chars you have to retype, if you lose a 1000 dollar payment it's a big headache for you and the customer.

Comment: @S.Lott: I think so. It would be harder for a computer to understand the context of the question but luckily I am a person and this it my interpretation, tho it can't be wrong too.

Comment: @Alix Axel: "e-commerce implies"... Interesting.  But.  You aren't asking this question.  The implications you see don't help clarify the question at all.

Comment: "serious e-commerce platform"?  What does this mean?  Please actually define your terms.  Please **update** the question to define what you mean.  Please be **specific**.  We can't guess.  Random guesses at your meaning will give you useless and confusing answers.

Comment: S.lott, my question was only to check the experience of people that did that! and i think my question was clear?

Answer (score 2):

I can't speak for the Django part since I've never used Python for web dev but [this blog post from Kyle Banker](http://kylebanker.com/blog/2010/04/30/mongodb-and-ecommerce/) is the best I've read so far describing the pros and cons of using MongoDB in e-commerce.

The hype around NoSQL (Mongo, Couch, ...) and e-commerce has mainly to do with [ontologies](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ontology), which are a very difficult thing to model into a fixed schema. For instance, fans, washing machines and HDDs all have the RPM attribute, while a monitor does not. Since it's impossible to model every classification and attribute for every product RDBMS usually rely on the very flexible [EAV data model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity-attribute-value_model) which is a pain in the ass to query / maintain in the long run.

Also, check out [MongoDB and Ecommerce: A Perfect Combination](http://www.slideshare.net/spf13/mongodb-and-ecommerce-a-perfect-combination).

Comment: thank you for that link, really interesting! thank you again :)

Comment: Kyle's blog is gone. I think this is the same info. https://raw.githubusercontent.com/banker/kylebanker.com/master/content/blog/2010/04/30/mongodb-and-ecommerce.txt

Answer (score 1):

You definitely gain flexibility by using MongoDB from the reasons that Alix has touched on, also it is very quick and sharding capabilities are built in, which means that scaling should be a bit easier.

However you will need ACID for certain aspects of what I believe you refer to e-commerce (a web version of a physical store, where you have products listed online, inventory control, sales records, etc) mainly around the issue of payment.

Long story short, if you break your "e-commerce" into 2 parts, being: " products listing" and "products purchasing" you can apply MongoDB to the first part and some ACID compliant (PostgreSQL, MySQL etc) to the 2nd part.

You'd need some sort of UUID for this of course.

Also, I'm not sure if this added complexity would be beneficial. If you choose to sell a restricted category of products, you can perhaps have smart SQL solution that'd still give you reasonable flexibility.

You could have for example all products in the same basic table, this table would have let's sat 20 columns for products' "features". Does a pair of jeans need all 20 columns? No, so use let's say 5. Does a car need all 20 columns? Maybe...

You could then have each product be associated with another table which would name the columns for you.

Comment: thank you for the answer, and sorry for being late :D
but, why do all people say that nosql is not good for transactions? i think nosql dbms are updating and gaining some "trust" :D